# Define a value in JSR223 Assertion and Access it from User Defined Variables in a Different Thread

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

Simply this is what I want help with,

Using Jmeter -

- Set a `variable` in the `JSR223 Assertion` in the `1st thread`
- Access that value in a `different threads` `User Defined Variables`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter Variables are [local to the current thread only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) therefore you won't be able to access the value outside the current thread (virtual user) context.

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads

So if you need to make some variable "global" you can convert it into a property like:

```
props.put('foo', 'bar')
```

in the JSR223 Assertion

Once done you should be able to access the value using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as `${__P(foo,)}` where required

You can also use [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) instead of setting the value in the JSR223 Assertion.

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method:

props.put("var","value");            // set property in 1st thread group

props.get("var");               // get property in 2nd thread group

Alternatively you can user "Inter-Thread Communication" plugins in JMeter.